# Is there any way to access database and execute queries using voice commands?

Tags: python, voice-recognition

i'm new in developing , is there any way to execute database queries using voice commands?

Comment: SQL itself has no such functionality.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the right place to ask this kind of questions but you can develop a small app with [voice recognition](https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/) and pass the voice command as a query for your db